Shooting on B&W infrared film with Canon L glasses
Canon EOS-1V manual says about shooting on B*W IR film:
Use a lens which provides IR index. With L-series lenses which do not have an infrared index, there is no need to compensate for infrared film.
My question is - why? How is that physically possible?
I also took a look at my Canon EF 70-200 f/2.8 IS II, and it has IR marks for 100mm and 70mm, but not for 200, so I assume Canon tells me that no focus correction for 200mm is neccesary with this lens.
Still don't understand why, though.


It sounds to me like the canon advice suggests that the lenses without an IR mark focus IR light equally to visible light.  In which case does your question become "What material/configuration does Canon use to equally focus IR and visible light in the same lens?"  (FWIW I've never shot IR  film with a Canon, and the last time I shot IR was in the late 90's and paid a lot of attention to the IR marks on my lenses)

Lenses may have different focus markings for infrared light because, basically, different wavelengths of light are (usually) brought into focus by a photographic lens at different points. This is also the reason we can experience chromatic aberration in photos (see below). By adjusting the lens's focus according to the infrared focus marking, then the infrared component of the light will be brought into focus at the correct point on the focal plane. There's more information about that in this existing question:
Why is infrared light's focus point different from that of visible light?

Returning to chromatic aberration, one way lens manufacturers counter this is by using apochromatic lens designs, which basically use special types of glass, e.g. fluorite. These lenses are better corrected to focus all wavelengths of light at the same point - including infrared light. Canon L lenses use fluorite lens elements. More reading at the Canon Camera Museum:
Fluorite lenses: Corrective capabilities beyond the limits of ordinary optical glass
Basically, the answer to the question is that Canon L lenses don't need infrared focus markings because there's already been an attempt to design/manufacture them in such a way as to focus infrared light at the same point as visible light in any case. Some L lenses may have infrared focus markings, which should be used when applicable - because not all lenses can be corrected perfectly.

Take a look at the focusing ring or scale of your camera (and others). Perhaps you will notice that as you focus, the focusing mechanism causes the camera lens to move as you make this adjustment. Focus on faraway objects and the lens comes to rest closer to film or digital sensor. Focus on nearby objects and the lens moves forward (distance lens to camera body stretches out).
Notice that when you are working in close (close-up) and focusing, the amount of lens movement to achieve focus is sizable. When working far distant objects the range of lens movement changes to almost insignificant. The result is close-up focusing is daunting whereas distance focusing grants lots of leeway.
As such, the difference in lens positioning for infrared light focusing when working distant objects is practically moot from the position for visible light, no need for a separate infrared index mark.
